# Use Farkas' Lemma to prove that either (1) $AX<0, BX=0$, or (2) $A^T u+B^T v=0$ for some $u,v$ with $u>0$

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

Suppose matrices $A_{p\times n}$ and $B_{q\times n}$. Use Farkas' Lemma to prove that one and only one of below systems has solution:

$$(1)\qquad AX<0,\quad BX = 0, \quad X\in\mathbb{R}^{n} $$
$$(2)\quad{A^T}u + {B^T}v = 0\quad\exists (u,v)\ \ u \ge 0,\ u \ne 0$$

Comment: is there any solution?

Comment: Well, firstly I don't think the question is clear, which might be a reason why it has no upvotes and no answers. What is $x$ and $X$? What does it mean when you put $\exists$ _after_ a formula? And is there any condition on $v$?

Comment: @tohecz, $v$ is free.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Lemma** (Farkas' lemma with $u \in \Bbb R^p$ *fixed*)
>
> *Fix* $u \ge 0$ and $u \ne 0$.  Let ${\bf b} = A^T u \in \Bbb R^n$, ${\bf D} = [-B^T \; B^T] \in M_{n \times 2q}(\Bbb R)$.  Exactly one of the following two statements holds.
>
> 1. $\exists {\bf x} = \binom{v^+}{v^-} \in \Bbb R^{2q}$ s.t. ${\bf Dx} = {\bf b}$ and ${\bf x} \ge {\bf 0}$
>
>    Let $v = v^+ - v^- \in \Bbb R^q$, which is free.  From ${\bf Dx} = {\bf b}$, we have $-B^Tv^++B^Tv^-=A^Tu$, so $A^Tu+B^Tv^+-B^Tv^- = A^Tu+B^Tv=0$.
> 2. $\exists {\bf y} \in \Bbb R^n$ s.t ${\bf y}^T{\bf D} \ge {\bf 0}$ and ${\bf y}^T{\bf b} < 0$
>
>    - From ${\bf y}^T{\bf D} = {\bf y}^T [-B^T \; B^T] \ge {\bf 0}$, we have $-{\bf y}^TB^T \ge {\bf 0}$ and ${\bf y}^TB^T \ge {\bf 0}$, so $B{\bf y} = {\bf 0}$.
>    - From ${\bf y}^T{\bf b} = {\bf y}^T A^T u = (A {\bf y})^T u = u^T A {\bf y} < 0$.

- $(2) \implies \neg (1)$: $\exists u \in \Bbb R^p, \exists v \in \Bbb R^q$ with $u \ge 0, u \ne 0$ such that ${A^T}u + {B^T}v = 0$.  If $(1)$ *holded*, $\forall x \in \Bbb R^n$, $Ax < 0, Bx = 0$ so $u^TAx \le 0$ (equality *would* not hold since $Ax$ is *strictly* negative and $u$ is nonnegative and *nonzero*) and $v^TBx = 0$, so $u^TAx + v^TBx \le 0$ *without* equality.  (*Strict* inequality *would* hold for some 
  component.)  This *would* contradict $(2)$.
- $\neg (2) \implies (1)$: $\forall u \in \Bbb R^p, \forall v \in \Bbb R^q$ with $u \ge 0, u \ne 0$, we have ${A^T}u + {B^T}v \ne 0$.  Apply the above lemma with $u = {\bf e}_i$, a standard unit vector, to get ${\bf y} \in \Bbb R^n$ such that $B{\bf y} = {\bf 0}$ and ${\bf e}_i^T A {\bf y} < 0$.  (The first case is excluded since we assume $\neg (2)$.)  So the $i$-th component of $A {\bf y}$ is negative, i.e. $A {\bf y} < 0$.

P.S. For readability, the variables corresponding to Farkas' lemma is **bolded**.